# Best Solution to get Stored Procedure returned header Names in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in **`Sql Server 2008`** with below body, that inserts car then gets it:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Car_Insert]
    @RunDate VARCHAR(25),
    @CarNo NVARCHAR(50),
    @Volume INT,
    @Weight SMALLINT,
    @CarName NVARCHAR(50),
    @InUse BIT,
    @CarID TINYINT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @CarID = ISNULL(MAX(c.CarID), 0) + 1
    FROM   Car c

    INSERT INTO Car
      (
        CarID,
        RunDate,
        CarNo,
        Volume,
        [Weight],
        CarName,
        InUse,
        IsDeleted
      )
    VALUES
      (
        @CarID,
        @RunDate,
        @CarNo,
        @Volume,
        @Weight,
        @CarName,
        @InUse,
        0
      )

    SELECT *
    FROM   Car
    WHERE  CarID = @CarID
END
```

I want to know if there is a way to get selected Columns headers info in T-SQL or not? **Is there any solution to get them?**

For example: we can get headers of function tables by `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINE_COLUMNS` table. Is there any info in **`sql server`** to get procedures returned headers?

Comment: do you mean you need column names?

Comment: yes, I want columns name and their data types.

Comment: Do you want this without actually executing the stored procedure?

Comment: yes i asked this question in T-SQL (sql server side)

Comment: Then no, there is no way to do that. You could have dynamic SQL or if statements that will make the SP return different columns for different executions depending on parameter values or the time of day etc...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx Note the deprecated warning and the alternatives.

Comment: @Nima, if you are wanting to get the parameters dynamically then you can reverse engineer `sp_help` as this infers information about a stored procedure, but not the output as @Mikael described.

Answer (score 2):

[`sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878236.aspx)

> This dynamic management function takes an @object_id as a parameter and describes the first result metadata for the module with that ID. The @object_id specified can be the ID of a Transact-SQL stored procedure or a Transact-SQL trigger.

It only describes the first result set.

Comment: could you please write an example for this? because i use sql server 2008 and this function is not supported in it.

Comment: Well tag your question with SQL Server 2008.